# Excel; Display value based on other value in same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, row

I need a formula that will find the highest value in the C column, and display the value of the A column of that same row

[image]

So something like MAX(C2:C8), and then display the "M. Stipić" value because its in the same row as the max value

I do not know how to display the value from Column 1 of the same row as the max value in a range.

Comment: `=INDEX(A2:A8;MATCH(MAX(C2:C8);C2:C8;0))`